# R reshape wide, change timevar order

Tags: r, reshape

I am using the reshape function on a date field and wonder if there is a way to change the order that fields are listed in the reshaped table.
I tried sorting the original table before the reshape but it didn't work.

```
DQ_Summary= data.frame(RuleID=c(1,2,1,2),
                      ProcessorTimeStamp=as.Date(c('2016-08-04','2016-08-04','2016-08-08','2016-08-08')),
                      ErrorCount=c(6,8,3,4))

#   RuleID ProcessorTimeStamp ErrorCount
# 1      1         2016-08-04          6
# 2      2         2016-08-04          8
# 3      1         2016-08-08          3
# 4      2         2016-08-08          4

Final_Summary = reshape(DQ_Summary,
                        timevar = "ProcessorTimeStamp",
                        idvar = c("RuleID"),
                        direction = "wide")
```

The above code returns a table that is formatted like:

```
#   RuleID ErrorCount.2016-08-04 ErrorCount.2016-08-08
# 1      1                     6                     3
# 2      2                     8                     4
```

I would like to see the order of the fields reshaped fields reversed:

```
#   RuleID ErrorCount.2016-08-08 ErrorCount.2016-08-04
# 1      1                     3                     6
# 2      2                     4                     8
```

It may seem trivial but it is something I need to have.

Comment: Please use quotes on the 'TimeStamp' column.

Comment: can you just reorder the columns after the reshape?

Comment: @rawr You reorder idea grabbed me and I came up with this: ColumnCount=ncol(Reshape_Counts)
DQ_Summary = Reshape_Counts[,c(1:4,ColumnCount:5)]

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do with `dcast` from `reshape2` after we convert the 'ProcessorTimeStamp' to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` Dates in the reverse direction

```
library(reshape2)
DQ_Summary$ProcessorTimeStamp <- factor(DQ_Summary$ProcessorTimeStamp, 
    levels = as.character(sort(unique(as.Date(DQ_Summary$ProcessorTimeStamp)),
                decreasing = TRUE)))
dcast(DQ_Summary, RuleID~ProcessorTimeStamp, value.var = "ErrorCount")
```

---

Or this can be done with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DQ_Summary %>%
       mutate(ProcessorTimeStamp = factor(ProcessorTimeStamp, 
           levels = as.character(sort(unique(as.Date(ProcessorTimeStamp)), 
              decreasing = TRUE)))) %>% 
       spread(ProcessorTimeStamp, ErrorCount)
#  RuleID 2016-08-08 2016-08-04
#1      1          3          6
#2      2          4          8
```